# Gmail Add-on pass parameters to function triggered by card action

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-addons

I'm building a Gmail add-on that creates a card with just one form button. Once clicked, I want the button to trigger a function that will send the open email's content to an external API.

So far, I have something like this:

```
function createCard(event) {
  var currentMessage = getCurrentMessage(event).getBody();
  var section = CardService.newCardSection();

  var submitForm = CardService.newAction()
    .setFunctionName('callAPI');

  var submitButton = CardService.newTextButton()
    .setText('Submit')
    .setOnClickAction(submitForm);

  section.addWidget(CardService.newButtonSet()
    .addButton(submitButton));

  var card = CardService.newCardBuilder()
    .setHeader(CardService.newCardHeader()
    .setTitle('Click this button'))
    .addSection(section)
    .build();

  return [card];
}

function callAPI(event) {
  var payload = { "msg": msg }; // msg is the parameter I need to get from the function call
  var options = {
        "method"  : "POST",
        "contentType": "application/json",
        "payload" : JSON.stringify(payload),
        "followRedirects" : true,
        "muteHttpExceptions": true
  };

  return UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://www.someAPI.com/api/endpoint', options);
}
```

How can I pass the `currentMessage` variable into the `callAPI` function? According to the documentation, the only parameter that we can get from an action function seems to be `event` that only has the form fields data. If there isn't a way to pass other parameters, is there a way for that function to get the context data of the message directly inside the function??

Thanks!

Comment: Is your issue solved?

Answer (score 7):

I believe the proper way to pass the currentMessage content to the callAPI function would be to use the setParameters as described in [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/action?hl=en#setParameters(Object))

Your code would look like this:

```
var submitForm = CardService.newAction()
    .setFunctionName('callAPI')
    .setParameters({message: currentMessage});
```

In the callback, your would fetch the message by using something like:

```
function callAPI(event) {
    var payload = event.parameters.message; 
    ...
```

As a reminder, both the key (message) as the value (currentMessage) must be Strings.

Comment: Thanks for this!  I couldn't find any other examples of how to read the parameters in the event handler.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Properties Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties), which allows you to store strings as key-value pairs. The idea would be to store the value of `currentMessage` in a property in the function `createCard`, and then use it in `callAPI`.

- First, to store the variable, you can add the following lines to `createCard` after declaring `currentMessage`:

```js
var userProperties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
userProperties.setProperty("currentMessage", currentMessage);
```

- Second, to retrieve this variable, add the following lines to `callAPI`:

```js
var userProperties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
var msg = userProperties.getProperty("currentMessage");
```

#### Update:

In order to avoid the limit of characters for a single property, you could also split your message into as many properties as were necessary.

- You would first have to split the message into an array via [substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring), and store each element of the array in a different property. You would have to add this to `createCard`, after declaring `currentMessage`:

```js
var messageArray = [];
var i = 0;
var k = 5000; // Character limit for one property (change accordingly)
while (i < currentMessage.length) {
  var part = currentMessage.substring(i, i += k);
  messageArray.push(part); // Splitting string into an array of strings
}
var userProperties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
userProperties.deleteAllProperties(); // Delete old properties
for (var j = 0; j < messageArray.length; j++) { // Set a different property for each element in the array
  userProperties.setProperty('messagePart' + j, messageArray[j]);
}
```

- Then, to retrieve the message body, you could first retrieve all the properties corresponding to the message, and then join all the values in a single string with [concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/concat). Add the following lines to `callAPI`:

```js
var userProperties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
var keys = userProperties.getKeys(); // Get all property keys
var j = 0;
var currentMessage = "";
do {
  var part = userProperties.getProperty('messagePart' + j);
  currentMessage = currentMessage.concat(part); // Concat each property value to a single string.
  j++;    
} while (keys.indexOf('messagePart' + j) !== -1); // Check if property key exists
```

#### Reference:

- [Properties Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties)
- [String.prototype.substring()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)
- [String.prototype.concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/concat)

I hope this is of any help.

Comment: Thanks @iamblichus! The only problem with this solution is that there's a limit on character count for the value passed to setProperty, so I can't use it to store the message body.

Comment: @uckc in that case, you could split your body into several properties. There is a limit to this too, but it's much higher. And this could be easily automated. If you think this could be a valid workaround, I'll update my answer with the corresponding code.

Comment: @uckc I updated my answer. This way, I think you can avoid the character limit issue. Please tell me if that works for you.

Comment: I tried splitting the string into multiple properties but it crashed the add-on and returned a timeout. In the end, I took a different approach and used Gmail's API to take care of forwarding the content of the email rather than through the API.