# Google apps script Exceeded maximum execution time

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I try to adapt my code to avoid the time limitation but it looks like it is not working. Can someone help me with that? what am I doing wrong?
It is running but not avoiding the time limitation problem.
The main function is a function that extracts many calendars from google calendar and does some easy calculation.
I receive a time limit restriction, for now, my solution was to create 8 codes and trigger them every hour, but I feel it is not super clean and we could do better.
Thanks a lot,
j.

```
function update_main_master() {
  var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Id Calendriers - Dates Debut et Fin"); //Sheet name where you will have the loop
  sheet2.getRange('d1').setValue(0);
  // Set filters
 
  var begin = new Date(); // Time when execution begins
  // Your code before loop
  export_gcal_to_gsheetLast1()
   // Your code before loop
  
  
  
  var x = sheet2.getRange('D1').getValue(); // Retrieve x stored in previous execution (from PropertiesService? Spreadsheet?) (should be 0 if first execution)
  var timeLimit = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 4 minutes (in milliseconds)
  while (new Date() - begin < timeLimit) { // Check if 5 minutes passed since execution start
    for (var x = 0; x < xngData.length && xngData[x][3] != undefined; x++) {
      
      // Your code inside loop
  export_gcal_to_gsheetLast1()
    // Your code inside loop
    }
  }
  // Store current x index (using PropertiesService? Or write to the spreadsheet itself?
  var ContorlSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById('IDssdfsadfsafd');
  var ContorlSh = ContorlSS.getSheetByName('Id Calendriers - Dates Debut et Fin');
  ContorlSh.getRange('e1').setValue('Updated');
  ContorlSh.getRange('f1').setValue(new Date());
  ContorlSh.getRange('d1').setValue(x);
  if (x < xngData.length) { // Create trigger if x hasn't reach the total number of iteration
    ScriptApp.newTrigger("update_main_master")
    .timeBased()
    .after(1000 * 20) // This fires the function 1 minute after the current execution ends. Change this time according to your preferences
    .create();  
  }
}
///////////////////////////////////////////export calendar////////////////
function export_gcal_to_gsheetLast1(){
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Extraction 1 - Calendrier");
  var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Id Calendriers - Dates Debut et Fin"); //Sheet name where you will have the list of calendar ID's, startDate and endDate

  sheet.clear() // If you'll be runnning the script several times, the data will be duplicated so I added this line to clear the sheet before adding the data
  // other option would be to create a script to check if data already exists before adding it to the sheet

  // Set filters
  var startDate = sheet2.getRange('k1').getValue(); //Range for startDate
  var endDate = sheet2.getRange('k2').getValue(); //Range for endDate
  var users = sheet2.getRange('b3:B').getValues(); //Range where you have the calendar ID's

  // Create a header record on the current spreadsheet in cells A1:N1 - Match the number of entries in the "header=" to the last parameter
  // of the getRange entry below
  var header = [["Titre", "Description", "Location", "Début", "Fin", "Heures effectives","Extraction 2","Extraction 3","Heures Planifiées", "Vacances", "Maladie","Congé légal", "Absence"]]
  var range = sheet.getRange(7,1,1,13);
  range.setValues(header);
  
  for (var j = 0; j< users.length; j++){
    //here we do the things we do once per calander
    if (users[j] == ""){
      break;
    }
    
    else{
      var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(users[j]);
      var events = cal.getEvents(startDate, endDate);

      // Loop through all calendar events found and write them out starting on the next empty row
      for (var i=0;i<events.length;i++) {
        var myformula_placeholder = '';
        var details=[
          [events[i].getTitle(), events[i].getDescription(), events[i].getLocation(), events[i].getStartTime(), events[i].getEndTime(), 
          myformula_placeholder,myformula_placeholder,myformula_placeholder,myformula_placeholder,myformula_placeholder,myformula_placeholder,myformula_placeholder,myformula_placeholder]
        ];

        var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow()+1;
        var range=sheet.getRange(lastRow,1,1,13);
        range.setValues(details);
          
        var cell=sheet.getRange(lastRow,6);
        cell.setFormula('=(HOUR(RIGHT(b' +lastRow+';5))+(MINUTE(RIGHT(b' +lastRow+ ';5))/60))-(HOUR(LEFT(b' +lastRow+ ';5))+(MINUTE(LEFT(b' +lastRow+ ';5))/60))')
        cell.setNumberFormat('.00');
        
        var cell=sheet.getRange(lastRow,7);
        cell.setFormula('=IFERROR(TEXT(INDEX(SPLIT(A'+lastRow+';" ");2);"hh:mm");"")')
        
        
        var cell=sheet.getRange(lastRow,8);
        cell.setFormula('=IFERROR(TEXT(INDEX(SPLIT(A'+lastRow+';" ");3);"hh:mm");"")')

        var cell=sheet.getRange(lastRow,9);
        cell.setFormula('=IF(OR(G'+lastRow+'="Maladie";G'+lastRow+'="Congé";G'+lastRow+'="Absence";G'+lastRow+'="00:00";G'+lastRow+'="Vacances");0;(HOUR(H'+lastRow+')+(MINUTE(H'+lastRow+')/60))-(HOUR(G'+lastRow+')+(MINUTE(G'+lastRow+')/60)))')

        var cell=sheet.getRange(lastRow,10);
        cell.setFormula('=IF(IFNA(VLOOKUP(D'+lastRow+'; feries;1;FALSE);1)<>1;0;IF(AND(G'+lastRow+'="00:00";H'+lastRow+'="Vacances");0,5;IF(G'+lastRow+'="Vacances";1;0)))')

        var cell=sheet.getRange(lastRow,11);
        cell.setFormula('=IF(G'+lastRow+'="Maladie";1;0)')

        var cell=sheet.getRange(lastRow,12);
        cell.setFormula('=IF(G'+lastRow+'="Congé";1;0)')
        
        var cell=sheet.getRange(lastRow,13);
        cell.setFormula('=IF(G'+lastRow+'="Absence";1;0)')

      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem with your script is that you are using methods like [`setFormula`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setformulaformula) or [`getRange`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column) inside of a loop, this causes a massive call to Spreadsheet service.

This is not recommended by the best practices guides [Minimize Call to other service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices#minimize_calls_to_other_services).

So, in order to solve this problem you have to use another recommendation from [Best Practices guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices), using [batch operation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices#use_batch_operations).

Instead of using [`setFormula`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setformulaformula) use [`setFormulas`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setformulasformulas) and delegate to Javascript all the tasks to build the formulas.

So all the lines that start with:

```js
var cell=sheet.getRange(lastRow,6);
cell.setFormula('=(HOUR(RIGHT(b' +lastRow+';5))+(MINUTE(RIGHT(b' +lastRow+ ';5))/60))-(HOUR(LEFT(b' +lastRow+ ';5))+(MINUTE(LEFT(b' +lastRow+ ';5))/60))')
```

Move to something like this:

```js
let formulas = []
for(let i = 0; i < 7; i++){formulas.push(FORMULAS)}
sheet.getRange(x,y,nx,ny).setFormulas(formulas)
```

This will be a starting point.

###### Documentation

- [**Best Practices Google Apps Script**](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices)

Comment: Hi @Emel, many thanks for your help!! Could you help with the first formula? I'm not sure i got your example right. for example .push(FORMULAS) should simply be .push('=(HOUR(RIGHT(b' +lastRow+';5))+(MINUTE(RIGHT(b' +lastRow+ ';5))/60))-(HOUR(LEFT(b' +lastRow+ ';5))+(MINUTE(LEFT(b' +lastRow+ ';5))/60))') ? i is the number of formulas I have ? thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes, this is only a pseudo-code sampling what has to be done. You don't need a for loop, just only need to `.push` the formulas to the array and append it later

Comment: Ok thanks ! So basically I just need this line :  sheet.getRange(x,y,nx,ny).setFormulas(formulas) ? I’ll try to modify the code with that. Still a bit confused but let’s test it.

Comment: Sorry If you misunderstand me , you need to full refactor your code in order to prevent the execution time issue. As I say in my answer this is only one of the things that you can do to improve your code.

Comment: Thanks Emel, I have tried to change it with your proposition but my skills are beginners skills and I was not able to make it work. What I have done is I simply created more functions with shorter start and end dates and then I consolidate them in a main sheet.

Comment: @Julien Glad to hear it! Consider up-votie or accept the answer

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the help of this amazing community. I was able to have a code that works so much faster. Thank you @Emel for your advices. Now it is working so much faster!!

````
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Extraction 8 - Calendrier");
  var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Id Calendriers - Dates Debut et Fin"); //Sheet name where you will have the list of calendar ID's, startDate and endDate

  sheet.clear() // If you'll be runnning the script several times, the data will be duplicated so I added this line to clear the sheet before adding the data
  // other option would be to create a script to check if data already exists before adding it to the sheet

  // Set filters
  var startDate = sheet2.getRange('k15').getValue(); //Range for startDate
  var endDate = sheet2.getRange('k16').getValue(); //Range for endDate
  var users = sheet2.getRange('b3:B').getValues(); //Range where you have the calendar ID's

  // Create a header record on the current spreadsheet in cells A1:N1 - Match the number of entries in the "header=" to the last parameter
  // of the getRange entry below
  const data = []
  const formulas = [];
  const headers = [["Titre", "Description", "Location", "Début", "Fin", "Heures effectives","Extraction 2","Extraction 3","Heures Planifiées", "Vacances", "Maladie","Congé légal", "Absence"]]

  
  for (var j = 0; j< users.length; j++){
    //here we do the things we do once per calander
    if (users[j] == ""){
      break;
    }
    
    else{
      var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(users[j]);
      var events = cal.getEvents(startDate, endDate);
      var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow()+8;

      // Loop through all calendar events found and write them out starting on the next empty row
      for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
        var details=
        [
          events[i].getTitle(), 
          events[i].getDescription(), 
          events[i].getLocation(), 
          events[i].getStartTime(), 
          events[i].getEndTime()
        ];

        data.push(details);
        const rowFormulas = 
        [
          '=(HOUR(RIGHT(b' +lastRow+';5))+(MINUTE(RIGHT(b' +lastRow+ ';5))/60))-(HOUR(LEFT(b' +lastRow+ ';5))+(MINUTE(LEFT(b' +lastRow+ ';5))/60))',
          '=IFERROR(TEXT(INDEX(SPLIT(A'+lastRow+';" ");2);"hh:mm");"")',
          '=IFERROR(TEXT(INDEX(SPLIT(A'+lastRow+';" ");3);"hh:mm");"")',
          '=IF(OR(G'+lastRow+'="Maladie";G'+lastRow+'="Congé";G'+lastRow+'="Absence";G'+lastRow+'="00:00";G'+lastRow+'="Vacances");0;(HOUR(H'+lastRow+')+(MINUTE(H'+lastRow+')/60))-(HOUR(G'+lastRow+')+(MINUTE(G'+lastRow+')/60)))',
          '=IF(IFNA(VLOOKUP(D'+lastRow+'; feries;1;FALSE);1)<>1;0;IF(AND(G'+lastRow+'="00:00";H'+lastRow+'="Vacances");0.5;IF(G'+lastRow+'="Vacances";1;0)))',
          '=IF(G'+lastRow+'="Maladie";1;0)',
          '=IF(G'+lastRow+'="Congé";1;0)',
          '=IF(G'+lastRow+'="Absence";1;0)'
        ]
        
        formulas.push(rowFormulas)
        lastRow=lastRow+1
      }
    }
  }

  sheet.getRange(7,1,headers.length, headers[0].length).setValues(headers)
  sheet.getRange(8,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data);
  sheet.getRange(8,data[0].length + 1,formulas.length, formulas[0].length).setFormulas(formulas);
  sheet.getRange(8,6,sheet.getLastRow()).setNumberFormat('.00');

}```
````